# Unable to perform arithmetic operations in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I hope you're well.

I've been toying with an SQL query recently but there's a column that is supposed to be the result of an arithmetic operation that does not seem to work for me. Here is the code I'm using:

```
select activecampaign.campaign_step,
       count(activecampaign.email_name) as email_opened,
       count(contracts.uuid) as contracts,
       count(contracts.uuid)/count(activecampaign.email_name)*100 as cr_rate

from il.mktg_activecampaign_email_opens activecampaign

full outer join bl.leads leads
    on leads.uuid = activecampaign.uuid

full outer join bl.contracts contracts
    on leads.uuid = contracts.uuid
    and contracts.conversion_channel = 'crm'

group by activecampaign.campaign_step
```

The first three select parameters are working just fine but the fourth one is not displaying anything I would expect. Here's a screenshot of the table it's producing:

[image]

My expectation here for the second row would be to see 3.86 but nothing of the sort is showing unfortunately.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction to solve this :) ?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: integer division  : (100.0  *count(contracts.uuid))/count(activecampaign.email_name)

Comment: I would change `count(contracts.uuid)/count(activecampaign.email_name)*100` to `100.0 * count(contracts.uuid)/count(activecampaign.email_name)`.

Comment: Case closed! Thank you @MitchWheat !